# Rubber on atomic scale during bending

Tags: elasticity

When you compare rubber with steel whats the difference on the atomic scale when you bend it?

Comment: Besides one is a polymer and one is a mixed-phase poly-crystalline metal?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of steel, bending and stretching does virtually nothing to the individual atomic bonds. Instead, it produces [dislocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation). The act of straining steel causes the dislocations to propagate through the material and coalesce in regions of high stress. In fact, this is the very reason that steel is so strong: steel consists of iron doped with small quantities of carbon. When the dislocations propagate through the steel, they hit one of the carbon defects and become 'pinned' there. In other words, the carbon acts as a sink for dislocations.

Rubber consists of very long polymers (natural rubber contains incredibly long chains of isoprene). While the monomeric units attach covalently together, the many individual polymeric chains are bound together via weak van der Waal forces.

In its natural state, these long chains are curled up in random configurations. When you stretch or bend the rubber, the molecules unravel into straight lines. It is the tendency to increase entropy that causes the polymers to curl up again and return to their previous state.

Comment: Are rubbers not usually network polymers? A linear polymer does not show elastomeric behaviour but usually thermoplastic - which is a huge difference.

Answer (score -1):

Rubber is made up of many different substances, but polymer is a good general definition.  Polymers are made from organic compounds and the atomic bonds between them are generally covalent bonds.  These properties combine to make the bonds between the molecules rather loose and mobile (as far as stretching and bending is concerned).
Metals, like the alloy steel, are totally inorganic and have metallic bonds, which keep the atoms very tightly packed and locked in place so that movement among the atoms is more limited.  Of course, as i'm sure you know, steel can still be bent, but a greater amount of force is required in order to break some of the metallic bonds.  You'll notice you can bend a steel spoon a few time back and fourth until it wears at the bend and eventually breaks apart.

If still seeking more knowledge try these useful links:
https://www.nde-ed.org/EducationResources/CommunityCollege/Materials/Structure/polymer.htm

and
https://www.boundless.com/chemistry/textbooks/boundless-chemistry-textbook/liquids-and-solids-11/crystals-and-band-theory-88/bonding-in-metals-the-electron-sea-model-388-3602/

I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is wrong. See mine above.